# Print a different text for that last record

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code with a FOR loop:

```
CourseGroup = pd.read_excel ('Desktop/Course_Group.xlsx', sheet_name='CourseGroups')
CourseGroupCourses = pd.read_excel ('Desktop/Course_Group.xlsx', sheet_name='CourseGroupCourses')
Courses = pd.read_excel ('Desktop/Course_Group.xlsx', sheet_name='Courses')
CGCwN = pd.merge(CourseGroupCourses, Courses, on='CourseId')
RC = pd.merge(CourseGroup,CGCwN, on = 'CourseGroupId', how = 'inner')

CourseGroups = RC.groupby('CourseGroupName')

    for group_name, df_group in CourseGroups:
        print(group_name)

        for group_name, row in df_group.iterrows():
            SubjectCode = row['SubjectCode']
            CourseNumber = row['CourseNumber']
            print('(Subject = {} AND CourseNumber = {}) OR'.format(SubjectCode, CourseNumber))
```

it produces the results I want BUT, I don't want the last record for each group to include the OR:

```
1A. Communication
(Subject = ENGL AND CourseNumber = 1301) OR
1B. Communication
(Subject = SPCH AND CourseNumber = 1315) OR
(Subject = SPCH AND CourseNumber = 1318) OR
(Subject = SPCH AND CourseNumber = 2333) OR
2. Mathematics
(Subject = MATH AND CourseNumber = 2313) OR
(Subject = MATH AND CourseNumber = 1332) OR
(Subject = MATH AND CourseNumber = 1342) OR
(Subject = MATH AND CourseNumber = 1350) OR
(Subject = MATH AND CourseNumber = 1324) OR
(Subject = MATH AND CourseNumber = 1314) OR
```

I can't figure out how to create an if statement so that

```
if it's the last record:
print('(Subject = {} AND CourseNumber = {})'.format(SubjectCode, CourseNumber))
else:
print('(Subject = {} AND CourseNumber = {}) OR'.format(SubjectCode, CourseNumber))
```

Any thoughts on how I could do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to determine how many records there are w/o iterating over them?

Comment: I don't think I do. I added 'Len': 
`for group_name, df_group in CourseGroups:
    print(group_name)
    
    for row_index, row in df_group.iterrows():
        SubjectCode = row['SubjectCode']
        CourseNumber = row['CourseNumber']
        Len = len(df_group) 
        print('(Subject = {} AND CourseNumber = {} {}) OR'.format(SubjectCode, CourseNumber, Len))`

it prints out the total number of records for each group
`1B. Communication
(Subject = SPCH AND CourseNumber = 1315 3) OR
(Subject = SPCH AND CourseNumber = 1318 3) OR
(Subject = SPCH AND CourseNumber = 2333 3) OR`

Comment: I was trying to compare to len(df_group), so that if the record number = len(df_group) then it's the last record. But I havent been able to successfully add a count or index to each record in a group